# Can you destruct an object and have nullish coalescing for potential undefined constants?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, object-destructuring, nullish-coalescing

I use React, so I have a props object, for example:

```
const props: { id: number, name?: string} = { id: 1 }; // not defining the `name`
const { id, name } = props; // here the `const name` becomes undefined forever and even if I use the defaultProps pattern of React, Typescript still shows warnings for potential undefined
```

Is there any way to use nullish coalescing while destructing the object?
I cannot use this (due to ESlint rule defined by the team):

```
const name = props.name ?? 'placeholder name';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a default value if the `name` is undefined, without using optional chaining:

```
const { id, name = 'placeholder name' } = props;
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but it works. Thanks for the answer. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

To solve this possible problem i do it

Example:

```js
const defaultValue = 'It's a Empty Value';

let {name, age, lastName} = person;

$('#div_Teste').append(`<p>Name: ${name ?? defaultValue}, Age ${age ?? defaultValue }, Last name: ${lastName ?? defaultValue}</p>`
```

I have put nullish on the moment to use the variables.